# How to assign TfrxUserDataset dynamically to Fastreport?

Tags: xml, delphi, fastreport

To report data from an XML document with FastReport, I have created TfrxUserDataSets that traverse XML nodes, check for EOF and get field values; one TfrxUserDataSet per 'level' of the XML document.
This works - when the userdatasets are put on a form and are assigned to the FastReport data bands at design time.
Is it possible to assign the userdatasets to the FastReport data bands at runtime? Or is there another way to report from XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign any `TfrxDataset` component to a FastReport's data band by using the report's `FindObject` function and the band's `DataSet` property at runtime.

Here is a little example:

```
var
  Band : TfrxDataBand;
begin
  Band := frxReport1.FindObject('MyBandName') as TfrxDataBand;
  Band.DataSet := frxUserDataSet1;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I also assigned a value to Band.DataSetName. Now it appears I also must set the Dataset property of all TfrxMemoViews on the report; if I don't, I get a message "Error in expression 'MasterDS."CARCODE"': Identifier expected", although 'MasterDS' is the DataSetName of the band containing the memo view.